# More than twenty 'IServiceProvider' instances have been created for internal use by Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-2.1

I am getting this warning in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 application

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10402]
> More than twenty 'IServiceProvider' instances have been created for internal use by Entity Framework. This is commonly caused by
> injection of a new singleton service instance into every DbContext
> instance. For example, calling UseLoggerFactory passing in a new
> instance each time--see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869049
> for more details. Consider reviewing calls on
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' that may require new service providers to be
> built.

After spending some time i figured out its happening in startup.cs. I am using IdentityServer3 + OpenIDCnnection for authetication.

After user successfully logs-in, The client application authorizes the user making sure user exists in the client application's database.

**Startup.cs of Client Application**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
        services.AddDbContext<Data.Entities.MyDBContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
                sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(sqlCommandTimeout));
        });
    
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // removed for brevity purpose
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                // removed for brevity purpose
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
           
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        Data.Entities.UserAccount userAccount = null;
                        using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
                        {
                            using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                            {
                                using (var accountService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAccountService>())
                                {
                                    userAccount = await accountService.Authorize(userName);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (userAccount == null)
                        {
                            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(string.Format("Could not find user for login '{0}' ", userName));
                        }                         
                    },                     
                };
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Account Service**

```cs
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private readonly MyDBContext_dbContext;

    public AccountService(MyDBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;     
    }

    public UserAccount Authorize(string userName)
    {
        // Ensures user exists in the database
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_dbContext != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
            // Free any other managed objects here.                    
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        _disposed = true;
    }   
}
```

`AccountService.Authorize(userName)` will get invoked for every successful login. And so on 21st successful user and onward i start seeing warning.

**Questions**

1>In `OnTokenValidated` event I am creating service provider and immediately disposing it. Why EF is still logging warning?
2>How do i get rid of this warning?

I get this warning even if i create 20+ DBContext using scope

[NET Fiddle DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E1diA7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by unnecessary building service provider.
The `context` parameter has HttpContext. And HttpContext provide access to ServiceProvider

```
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    Data.Entities.UserAccount userAccount = null;
                    
                    using (var accountService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAccountService>())
                    {
                       userAccount = await accountService.Authorize(userName);
                    }
                        

                    if (userAccount == null)
                    {
                        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(string.Format("Could not find user for login '{0}' ", userName));
                    }                         
                },
```

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on some of the other answers - this can happen with Npgsql if you always use a new `NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder`.

Before:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DevaQueueDbContext>((options) => { 
    var dbDataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"));
    options.UseNpgsql(dbDataSourceBuilder.Build());
});
```

After:

```cs
var dbDataSource = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")).Build();

services.AddDbContext<DevaQueueDbContext>((options) => { 
    options.UseNpgsql(dbDataSource);
});
```

Comment: Same here, I put SourceBuilder in DbContext.OnConfiguring for Enum mapping, but later led to this issue. Pulling the SourceBuilder out solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as this is the top result for this exception, for those running into this same exception, but in a different situation, check the answers given here:

[EF Core internal caching and many DbContext types during testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503024/ef-core-internal-caching-and-many-dbcontext-types-during-testing)

Specifically the explanation in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504238/402185

And the specific situation I ran into here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76212845/402185

Summarizing: if your `DbContextOptionsBuilder` results in different options upon every creation of the data context, you'll eventually run into this exception. In my case, I added an `interceptor` to my `optionsBuilder` in the `OnConfiguring` method by instantiating it there.

Instead, move the creation of the interceptor to a static variable to make sure the used interceptor instance is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Instead of disposing the dbcontext, you can define ServiceLifetime argument of AddDbContext method.

> contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime
>
> The lifetime with which to register the DbContext service in the container.
>
> optionsLifetime :  ServiceLifetime
>
> The lifetime with which to register the DbContextOptions service in the container.

[EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext)

(2) Bellow is the sample of logger and error trap, that could be apply to configureservices method in startup class.

```cs
// define single service provider
 using (var sp = new ServiceCollection()
                   .AddLogging(l => l.AddConsole())
                   .AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer("Server=(local);Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True",
                        sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(120));
                     })
                    .BuildServiceProvider())
 
 // define service logger
 using (var logger = sp.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Program>())
 {
      try
      {
          for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
          {
              using (var serviceScope = sp.CreateScope())
              using (var accountService = sp.GetService<MyDBContext>())
              {
                  
              }
          }
      }

     // (2) catch the error warning
     catch(ex: Exception)
     {
          logger.LogInformation($@"Error: {ex.ToString()}");
     }
 }
```

Btw, definitely EF entities are static classes for both declaration and runtime. Therefore you must modify (or doing any migration steps) the class(s) when the database schema changes.

Hope this helps.