# EF7 upgrade - ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning: More than twenty 'IServiceProvider' instances have been created for internal use by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I'm working on upgrading EF 6 to 7 in an application I'm maintaining and this exception is now being thrown after some time or a certain action is being performed (I haven't figured out what the trigger is). Here's what's being logged by our `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`:

```
2023-06-29 15:18:08.7369|ERROR|SAI.Web.Application.Middlewares.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.|System.InvalidOperationException: An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning': More than twenty 'IServiceProvider' instances have been created for internal use by Entity Framework. This is commonly caused by injection of a new singleton service instance into every DbContext instance. For example, calling 'UseLoggerFactory' passing in a new instance each time--see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869049 for more details. This may lead to performance issues, consider reviewing calls on 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' that may require new service providers to be built. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.EventDefinition.Log[TLoggerCategory](IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreLoggerExtensions.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, ICollection`1 serviceProviders)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|4_1(IDbContextOptions _, ValueTuple`2 arguments)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext, ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext, ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext, ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method39(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Refdata.SAI.Web.Application.Middlewares.UserSetterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, UserManager usermanager) in D:\BuildAgents\BuildAgent08\_work\325\s\Source\Refdata.SAI.Web.Application\Middlewares\UserMiddleware.cs:line 38
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I've tried to follow the recommendations mentioned in the exception.

> This is commonly caused by injection of a new singleton service instance into every DbContext instance. For example, calling 'UseLoggerFactory' passing in a new instance each time

The `SaiContext` only takes the options as constructor arguments:

```cs
internal partial class SaiContext : DbContext
{
    public SaiContext(DbContextOptions<SaiContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    [...]
}
```

The `SaiContext` is registered (by default) as `Scoped` as well as repositories and the unit of work using it

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddEntityFrameworkRepositories(this IServiceCollection services, Action<DataConfiguration> configureOptions)
{
    var dataConfiguration = new DataConfiguration();
    configureOptions(dataConfiguration);

    services.Configure(configureOptions);

    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

    services.AddDbContext<SaiContext>(builder =>
                                      {
                                          builder.UseSqlServer(dataConfiguration.ConnectionString, options => options.MaxBatchSize(500))
                                                 .AddInterceptors(new TemporalPropertiesSetterInterceptor());
                                      });

    return services;
}
```

If you're wondering what the `TemporalPropertiesSetterInterceptor` is, [here's the explanation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26463#issuecomment-1558631148).

I don't want to silence/ignore this warning without understanding the cause.

Any hint to understanding why I'm encountering this exception and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no EF 7, there's EF *Core* 7. Neither EF nor EF Core has any `IRepository` or `IUnitOfWork` interfaces nor are they needed because a DbContext *already is* a Unit Of Work. In fact, that's a very strong smell. The stack trace shows the errors are thrown by `Refdata.SAI.Web.Application.Middlewares.UserSetterMiddleware`. What is that code doing? What does `TemporalPropertiesSetterInterceptor` do?

Comment: Let me clarify: EF Core 7. Neither repositories nor the unit of work are at cause, I wanted to provide some context. UserSetterMiddleware is not at cause, it's the entry point calling the next middleware in the pipeline.

Comment: `If you're wondering what the TemporalPropertiesSetterInterceptor is,` post that in the question itself, explaining *why* you use that code.

Comment: `is not at cause` on the contrary, those DAO (not repository) *anti*-patterns are behind most EF questions here. You're putting a low-level CRUD class called "Repository" over a high-level abstraction like a domain repository and unit of work. We can't guess what the implementation in those classes is. In their most benign form they're just aliases for EF Core methods. Worst case, there are `Insert` methods that actually execute DELETEs because they call `SaveChanges` after every call, and a long-running transaction that results in deadlocks

Comment: In any case, this question refers to classes, code and tables that aren't included in the question itself, changing how EF Core itself works. Post enough code so *other people* can reproduce the issue.

Comment: According to the exception it does not: consider reviewing calls on 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' that may require new service providers to be built

Comment: OK, you win. EF Core 7 is broken and nobody can reproduce your issue because nobody has your code. That doesn't help you. If you want help, create a *simple* console application with the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. But *do* consider whether you're misusing EF Core. I bet if I [use temporal tables using EF Core's built in functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/temporal-tables) I won't have any problem retrieving current, older or period data, or SELECTing the period fields

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60047465/more-than-twenty-iserviceprovider-instances-have-been-created-for-internal-use See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877339/396005

Comment: The issue linked as being answered by represents exactly my issue and fixes it.